# Android emulator screen tilted 180°

Tags: android, android-emulator, rotation, screen

I wrote an Activity whose orientation I wanted to be "portrait" only. I realized this by putting the

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

statement into the manifest.xml:

```
<activity
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation">
</activity>
```

When I start this activity on the AVD (Android 4.0.3 - API Level 15) the whole screen is tilted by 180° in portrait mode. When I start it on my Samsung GT-P3100 Galaxy Tab 2 7.0'' the screen is NOT tilted by 180° but shows correctly.

I could not find any help regarding this problem but only descriptions of how to rotate the whole emulator (which is NOT what I want to do). Thank's for your help!

-Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe thats because the created AVD has a display which could wrap your activity screen without rotation. Also don't take emulator too serious you should always check it on real devices. Also there are devices which has Landscape native orientation. They are usually tablets which has hires displays additionally.

Answer (score 0):

If AVD was created by you, replace width and height with each other, for example if width is 600 and height is 1024, set width to 1024 and height to 600.